# My Root Folder isn't create in android 10?

Tags: java, android, directory, save

I Download music and want to play in my recycler, everything is ok in all android but in android 10 the root isn't created, here is my code :

```
     File parent = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), ".RingTones2020");
    final String songPath = "/" + arrayListNames[pos] + ".mp3";
    final String loc = parent + songPath;
    final File checkFile = new File(parent, songPath);
```

Please Help me...

Comment: Your code does not try to create a root folder. Or any other folder. So where are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getExternalStorageDirectory` is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()) in Android 10, you should check out new restrictions for accessing storage called [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage). for just Android 10 you can opt out and add `requestLegacyExternalStorage` flag to manifest, but Scoped Storage will be mandatory in Android 11 and above

Comment: so, what the best way that I can do now?

Comment: `you should check out new file providing api ` There is no new api. No new functions. The whole point is that old code does not work anymore. Scoped Storage is a restriction of that what used to function. Not an extension.

Answer (score 1):

In Api level 29 this method is deprecated..
You can't access the user's storage directly..
If you want to save any files, there will be few ways based on your use cases..

1. Scoped storage (not accessible for other apps)
2. Using MediaStore (for media files)

See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) for more details